# Error Code: 1054 Unkown column in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run this query:

```
SELECT name
FROM customers Left Join(
SELECT customerID as quantity
FROM ORDERS NATURAL JOIN ORDERCONTENTS
GROUP BY customerID)AS quantity
ON customers.customerID=quantity.customerID
ORDER BY name;
```

and each time I run it I get this error:

```
SELECT* FROM customers LEFT JOIN( SELECT customer AS quantity FROM ORDERS 
NATURAL JOIN ORDERCONTENTS GROUP BY customerl... 

Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'quantity.customerID' in 'on clause'
```

I have tried different joins and columns but it continues to return the same error. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: To clarify this is a homework question testing the use of functions and such along with a sub-query. The goal is to:

Retrieve the name of every customer and how many pizzas they have ordered (NULL if no pizzas ordered).

The question itself is provided in this awful template, I only have control over:

1) What is selected

2)The first FROM (customers LEFT JOIN)

3) The input for the GROUP BY.

Unforutnately I am un able to edit any of the following:

```
 FROM ORDERS NATURAL JOIN ORDERCONTENTS

 as quantity
 ON customers.customerID=quantity.customerID
 ORDER BY name;
```

Apologies for the intial lack of information

Comment: You have aliased customerid as quantity in sub query.

Comment: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3f7db0370a599518881c95b7f9236ac0)

Comment: Couple of things I don't like here, natural join and group by without aggregation.

Comment: Your query is quite malformed and you haven't explained what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: you'd better using different aliases for `the subquery` and the column `customerID` inside that.

Comment: Sorry I'll edit the question and clarify a bit further.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code you named your customerID column in the orders table as quantity

So you should just need to change the ON clause to

```
ON customers.customerID=quantity.quantity
```

I would also advise changing the column name to something other than quantity to avoid ambiguity, since you are naming 2 things as "quantity".